# cannot see photo clearly from ipod touch library locally

Tags: iphone, ios, ipod-touch, ipod

I have an ipod touch and ios 9.1. When I started to use an iCloud, all my photos have uploaded to my iCloud account. So when I'm offline I cannot see particular photo clearly, i have to find somewhere wifi for internet connection to download this particular photo from my iCloud account. Is there any setting where i can set all my photos to be fully loaded from iCloud account whenever I want to see any of them. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Settings**, select **iCloud**, then **Photos**, and then turn on **Download and Keep Originals**. This will move all of your iCloud photos in full resolution to your iPod.